# How can I solve Data reshape error in anaconda python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, reshape

I have a sample data such as : name, AVg, GPA

Here is some part of data I've got. I have 164 rows of data

[image]

```
sample = pd.read_excel('./data.xlsx')
X = sample.AVG
y = sample.GPA


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

when I run above code I got error message saying 'With n_samples=1, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.'

so I added bleow code

```
X =np.reshape(-1,1)
y=np.reshape(-1,1)
```

Now I am getting error message saying 'With n_samples=1, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.'

How Can I remove those error message?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: print the shape of X and Y, you will understand the problem.. 
X is a single array and it is considered as 1 sample if you read the error message. 
Expand the dims using np.expand_dims and try.

Comment: I've check shape of X and y uisng print(X.shape), print(y.shape) and both output is (1,) so I added 
np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
np.expand_dims(y, axis=0) to the code above and still getting same error of 'With n_samples=1, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.' Am I missing something?

Comment: @H.Cho Did you check that the `expand_dims()` was successful/behaved as expected?

Comment: @AMC Hi there, I added np.expand_dims(X, axis=0), np.expand_dims(y, axis=0 and run the code but got the error message saying With n_samples=1, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.

Comment: @H.Cho Did you check the arrays after expanding, is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Solve this prob by 
X_train=X_train.values.reshape(-1,1)
y_train=y_train.values.reshape(-1,1)